# How do I make include use local directories in php

Tags: php

I have created a function that uses images and such in a different directory but when i call for it using include it looks for the image in the directory where the include is located. What would i use so that the file is ran in the directory it is located and outputs the function in the new php script?

Comment: Have you considered telling it which directory it should use?

Comment: Why don't you either pass it the folder you want searched in a parameter, or have the correct folder coded into the function?

Comment: Yes i have, but im going to be using this function on many pages. Maybe i should move images from that directory and locate them all to one folder on the server?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your script to use its location on the server, which should be the same regardless of where it is include()'d

```
<?php
$path_of_this_script = dirname(__FILE__); 
[...]
```

Comment: Oops :) not thinking straight.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has the chdir function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php

I don't see why you wouldn't use html though in the  to specify the image location.

Answer (score 0):

By default, any code without the proper parameters will look for resources in the local directory. So to solve your problem, you could do several things. Here is one example:

Lets assume your directory structure is as follows:

- home/
- images/
- -icon.png
- files/
- -abc.php
- -vars.php

In abc.php, you may have something like this

```
<?php
function include_image() {
  $image_url = "icon.png"; // Will search for icon.png in "files" directory
  //do something with $image_url
}
?>
```

You could do the following:

In vars.php, include an image path

```
<?php
$image_path = "http://www.example.com/images"; // or "foldername/subfoldername/images"
?>
```

Change your code in abc.php to the following

```
<?php
include "vars.php";
function include_image() {
  $image_url = "$image_path/icon.png"; // Will search for icon.png in "files" directory
  //do something with $image_url
}
?>
```

Comment: I used this method, Thank you so much, explained it well, now i have a better understanding of how directories work :)